# Set which is both ring and monotone class it is $\sigma$-ring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be both a ring and monotone class. Show that $S$ is a $\sigma$-ring.

---

#### My attempt

I want to show that $S$ contains $\emptyset$ and it is closed under countable unions and set difference.

1. $\emptyset\in S$ because $S$ is a ring
2. Let $A, B \in S$ then $A \setminus B \in S$ because $S$ is a ring
3. Let $A_k$ be an arbitrary family of sets $\in S$.
   Define family of sets $B_n = \cup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ then $B_1 \subset B_2 .. \subset B_n ...$ Hence $A = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i} \in S$ because $S$ is monotone class.

Is this solution acceptable?

Comment: Looks correct to me, maybe I would write $\bigcup^\infty B_i=\bigcup^\infty A_k\in S$. You only needed to show closure under countable unions since the other properties come for free.

Comment: Thank you! ....